# git remote add <name> <url> doesn't seem to work on windows

Tags: windows, git

I'm using win 7 with git bash integrated into the windows command prompt. I have a repo where I'm trying to add another remote. I do this:

```
git remote add myserver ssh://git@subdomain.domain.com/blabla.git sources
```

Now git responds with:

```
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

    -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=<push|fetch>]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from
```

I find that puzzling since I thought this is what I had done. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's that "sources" at the end?

Comment: That's the source folder on the server. I reused everything after `myserver` from a `git clone` command.

Comment: The documentation shows nothing after `<url>`.

Comment: Ha! I did `git remote add myserver ssh://git@subdomain.domain.com/sources` and it worked! Thanks! If you write an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

The word `sources` at the end is causing the problem. The documentation you cited shows nothing after `<url>`. If it's a folder name, just attach it to the URL:

```
git remote add myserver ssh://git@subdomain.domain.com/sources
```